# jQuery JavaScript : How to keep track of actions done by users?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webpage with images. 
A user can click on images to show() or hyde() these images.

Sometimes, the user opens a popup to watch a video.

Then the code hide() all elements previously opened.

When the user closes the video, i need  to know which elements was previously opened in order to show only them.

What is the best way to do that ?

What i've done :

I've created an array and i push images names into it.

```
var arr_popup_open = [];
```

Then, this function is called when user open a popup and hide all elements :

```
function toggleAllPopup() {
if( $('#popup_micro_1').is(":visible"))
        {
            $('#popup_micro_1').hide();
            arr_popup_open.push('#popup_micro_1');
        }
if( $('#popup_micro_2').is(":visible"))
        {
            $('#popup_micro_2').hide();
            arr_popup_open.push('#popup_micro_2');
        }
if( $('#popup_micro_3').is(":visible"))
        {
            $('#popup_micro_3').hide();
            arr_popup_open.push('#popup_micro_3');
        }
    }
// and so on ... I have 7 images so it seems it's not very well optimized
```

When i need to show only images previously opened, i execute this code, a loop to show() elements in array.

```
$('#close_pop_up').click(function() {
    for(var i= 0; i < arr_popup_open.length; i++)
    {
        $(arr_popup_open[i]).show();
    }
});
```

What do you think about that ? Is there a better way to to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways you could go about this with jQuery.  Your way should work, but if you want to reduce the amount of code you could do something like:

```
var visibleDivs = $('div:visible', '#ContainerDiv');
```

Alternatively you could add a specific class to all visible elements when you show them and use:

```
var visibleDivs = $('.someClassName');
```

When hiding them due to your popup, you can store the list in the data of any element.  In this case, putting it on #close_pop_up might make sense:

```
visibleDivs.hide();
$('#close_pop_up').data('myDivs', visibleDivs);
```

When you want to show them again in your click function:

```
$('#close_pop_up').click(function() {
    $(this).data('myDivs').show();
});
```

Comment: I didn't know .data(), thanks it's what i need... I'll try your solutions

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine to me. Just remember to clear `arr_popup_open` in the start of the toggleopen function.

The alternative you could do if you really wanted is to keep the information of what is open or closed in Javascript variables that get updated when you open and close things. This way you don't need to depend on complex things such as `is(:visible)`

Comment: Yes, the array have to be cleared. I will use variables as you suggest. In that case, the variable can be some text, something like var image_1; when the function is called : image_1="open" and so on. Then an if statement if(image_1 == "open") and so on. Do you think i can use other types of variables ?

Comment: I guess the answer to this last question about variables is given by 
beezir by using .data()

Comment: For the variables, I usually prefer using hash tables keys corresponding to the ids of the divs: `var isVisible = {}; isVisible['popup_micro_1] = false;`, etc. I find it clearer then having tons of unrelated variables or having data hidden inside the ducument.